# Difference between [ ] and [, , ] in python

Tags: python

```
#string indexing

import random

word = "index"
print "The word is:" , word, "\n"

high = len(word)
low = -len(word)

for i in range(10):
    position = random.randrange(low,high)
    print "word[", position, "]\t", word[position]

raw_input("\n\nPress the enter key to exit,")
```

I copy this from a book called "Guide to Programming with Python". I'm not sure why do we have to add two commas in

```
[", position, "]
```

What does it mean? And why do i get error when I removed the two commas?

Comment: you're getting it wrong; `[", position, "]` is not a whole, what you're doing is just splitting part of different arguments. In the line where that appears the `print` function (statement) is being called with **four different arguments separated with commas**, the first arugment is the string `"word["`, the second one is the variable `position`, the third one another string `"]\t"` and finally the fourth one a variable `word[position]`. If you remove the commas you are completely breaking the Python syntax.

Comment: are you referring to the commas in `print "word[", position, "]\t", word[position]`? (because I don't see that bit anywhere else) - Those you need to separate arguments (for `print` in this case) as you have a string, a variable (integer), another string and a character (of a string variable)

Answer (score 0):

In python3

```
print("word[", position, "]\t", word[position])
```

"word[",  position , "[\t",  word[position] are arguments of [print()](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html?highlight=print#print)